# Вопрос по Kohana + Redis

Tags: php, redis, kohana, github

Как я понял,  на официальном сайте Redis не указаны модули, которые бы  подошли для Kohana.
Не могли бы подсказать какой-то с github. Желательно с мануалом, как пользоваться.

Только разбираюсь с Redis, поэтому чем больше информации, тем лучше.

Заранее благодарю.

```
/**
 * configuration file for connecting to RedisDB
 * uses Redisent driver
 * 
 * change the name (or copy this file) to 'redis.php' and fill your values
 */

return array(
    'default' => array(
        'driver' => 'Redisent',
        'dsn' => 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379',
    )
);
```

Comment: Очень советую пересобрать сборку php, установив расширение `extension_redis`, потому как клиентские библиотеки очень медленные и с множеством неудобств.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первая ссылка в Яндексе, вероятно, подойдет. https://github.com/magnax/kohana-redis-orm

Ну, нельзя же быть настолько ленивым! В config указано при ссылке на redisent:  * configuration file for connecting to RedisDB
 * uses Redisent driver

В Яндексе набираем redisent, получаем ссылку на Git https://github.com/jdp/redisent

---

Так искать проще: http://help.yandex.ru/search/how-to-search/basic-features.xml
=)

**Обновление**

Do you speak english?
Http://Translate.google.com

Вообще неясно, где ты увидел эту строку. На странице с `redisent` на `github` написано:

> Redisent has no dependencies aside
> from requiring PHP versions 5.3 and
> later. To add it to your project,
> simply drop the Redis.php file into
> your project structure, instantiate a
> Redis instance, and start issuing
> commands.

Добавь файл redis.php с github в структуру проекта и укажи необходимые настройки. `Redisent` начнет использоваться.

**Обновление**

1. Вот этот файл https://github.com/magnax/kohana-redis-orm/blob/master/ohm/config/redis_example.php переименовать в redis.php в папке config.
2. Вот это в папку modules https://github.com/jdp/redisent/tree/master/src/redisent
3. Включить модуль redis в bootstrap.php

Если ничего не напутал, то должно заработать. Иначе - см. подключение собственных модулей в kohana. Посмотри аналогичное подключение модуля для mysql - где хранится config, сам модуль и как подключается в bootstrap.php

Comment: Наверное, вы будете недовольны, но все же:
 
* change the name (or copy this file) to 'redis.php' and fill your values

куда копировать  в 'redis.php'?   
как заставить его все-таки правильно заработать с Redisent?

Comment: это я взял из redis_example.php
/*код добавил в вопрос*/

и добавить  в структуру проекта, вы имеете в виду подключить модулем в bootstrap.php или с помощью require в один из файлов OHM.php или RedisDB.php?

Comment: Так и делал, кроме переименования файла. Все равно  

ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Class 'Redisent' not found
MODPATH\ohm\classes\RedisDB.php [ 19 ] 

Буду смотреть, читать, как вы сказали, про модули.